# Problems with showing web site in iFrame in UIWebView in iPhone app?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, xcode, jquery-mobile

Instead of using PhoneGap or a similar framework, we would like to show a jQuery Mobile site inside a native shell on the iPhone using a UIWebView.

We don't need access to the hardware and are essentially wrapping a mobile site for the iPhone App Store.

Has anyone had, or see any, problems with this approach (e.g., showing embedded videos)?

Does anyone have references or code samples on best practices for doing this?

We're on Xcode 4.2.

Thanks!

Comment: There might be a problem with app store acceptance. In one of the Apple app store guidelines docs it says native apps that are nothing more than wrappers for a web site won't be accepted.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! It's actually a mobile site designed expressly for the iPhone ... so it's not publicly available. All the tutorials we find are for Xcode 3.x. Do you have suggestions on where we can find tutorials on embeddeding UIWebView & iFrames for Xcode 4.x?

Comment: There's nothing special about using UIWebView over using anything else in XCode 4, so any tutorial on how to use XCode will apply to UIWebView. If you google you should be able to find plenty of tutorial on how to use UIWebView itself. As its a web site you want to load you basically just give it the url and tell it to load it and off it goes. It should handle the html and js and jquery and iframes automatically. If you have any problems or specific questions come back here. Playing embedded videos is possible (using html5 is best) but there's a few gotchas you need to know.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! What are the gotchas?

Comment: You'll need to add this webkit-playsinline to the video tag in the html5, and also need to set the UIWebView's allowsInlineMediaPlayback property to YES. (Also if you register your own gesture recognizer on the UIWebView there is a bug in sharing the events with the controls for the video in some circumstances)